# why is pyglet failing to display my image?

Tags: python, image, display, pyglet

I am using the latest pyglet and having extreme trouble displaying images. I have stripped my code down to the bare essentials and am baffled by the result:

```py
import pyglet

pyglet.resource.path.append('Assets')
pyglet.resource.reindex()

look = pyglet.resource.image('skybox0.jpg')
print('image size',(look.width, look.height))

window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600, caption='check my Cube Maps')

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear
    look.blit(0,0)
    return

pyglet.app.run()
```

Here's what happens:

> ```py
> image size (256, 197)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:/Python/Python36/Dhruve and me/Pyglet/skybox look.py", line 19, in <module>
>    pyglet.app.run()
>  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 107, in run
>    event_loop.run()
>  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 167, in run
>    timeout = self.idle()
>  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 243, in idle
>    window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
>  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 1333, in dispatch_event
>    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
>  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 408, in dispatch_event
>    if handler(*args):
>  File "C:/Python/Python36/Dhruve and me/Pyglet/skybox look.py", line 16, in on_draw
>    look.blit(0,0)
>  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 1614, in blit
>    glInterleavedArrays(GL_T4F_V4F, 0, array)
>  File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\lib.py", line# 107, in errcheck
>    raise GLException(msg)
> pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: None
> ```

The image happens to be a skybox which displays fine when viewed by windows explorer. 
I'm on windows10 and python36.

Comment: Have you tried other images?

Comment: I get the same result with any of my .jpg and ,png images

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. But a small hygenic thing would be to remove the `return` in your `on_draw`, doesn't really do anything and there for serves no purpose :) Also `window.clear` should be `window.clear()`, otherwise you're not actually calling the function :) How big is your image and how fast does this issue come for you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks v much for your suggestion -
correcting the .clear  to .clear() made it work perfectly.
I need to see an optician...